# Error using mapview package: (!is.na(getProjection(lst[[i]]))) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, raster, r-sf

I am trying to use the mapview package to plot a raster and sf feature.

```
streamsTransform <- st_transform(streams, 2958)
st_crs(streamsTransform)

dem17N <- projectRaster(dem, crs = "+proj=utm +zone=17 +ellps=GRS80 
                        +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")

course <- raster::aggregate(dem17N,8)
mapview(course) + mapview(streamsTransform)
```

I have made sure they are in the same projected coordinate system using st_transform and projectRaster, but I am still getting the following error:

```
(!is.na(getProjection(lst[[i]]))) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, it is puzzling. I tried what I thought was a 'search for this error string' in the [mapview_github](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/tree/develop/R) trolling through all the R files there. So, presumably the error comes from something that `mapview` calls, uses, and returns (or attempts to) from. So look at the DESCRIPTION file for what else is called, imported & etc. This last part is a note to me, but you can do too [DESCRIPTION](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/blob/develop/DESCRIPTION) and track down the beast in the wild. Enter error txt in 'find in page' firefox. Sweet.

Comment: This is a temporary hick-up and should be solved soon. In fact, it is already solved in the development version of **mapview**. If you `remotes::install_github("r-spatial/mapview@develop")` things should work. The reason is that **sf** has recently changed how crs is handeled (due to changes in the system library GDAL that **sf** wraps). I am planning to release a new and fixed version of **mapview** to CRAN this weekend.